# Prepared statement needed if the user data format was changed?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sanitization

I use JCalendarChooser and user data was in `d MMMM yyyy` format. Example output is `4 November 2015`. Before I `SELECT` from database I change it to `yyyy-MM-dd` format. This is my code before `SELECT`:

```
                String date1 = null;

                java.util.Date d1 = jDateChooser1.getDate();
                if (d1 == null) {
                    System.out.println("No date specified!");
                } else {
                    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    date1 = fmt.format(d1); //jdatechooser
                    // Then select from db
                }
```

The way I understand about user validation is you need to sanitize all input from user but what if the data format was changed? Do I need to use prepared statements in such case above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no other way for input to get from the user to the query **except by passing through (and being validated by) the jDateChooser and SimpleDateFormat**, then your input is adequately sanitized.

That said, there are other reasons to use a PreparedStatement over a dynamic SQL string. If you run the same query multiple times with different dates, then each dynamic SQL string thus produced will be regarded by the dbms as a *new* query to be compiled from scratch, while a PreparedStatement will produce a single fill-in-the-blanks execution plan which can be reused without recompilation. This can result in improved performance on an oft-repeated query, which is A Good Thing™.